# Trouble installing tinyMCE and UniSharp/laravel-filemanager

Tags: php, laravel, tinymce

So Im trying to install tinyMCE with image upload. I successfully install tinyMCE for simple styling but I cant make the image upload to work. I try to installed UniSharp/laravel-filemanager but when I click on the img icon this is what I get

[Sorry page not found](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tZ9hq.png)

[Console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wG6lM.png)

I think somthing is wrong with the cmsURL

This is the index.blade.php

```
@extends('templates.layout')

@section('head')
  <script src="/wysiwyg/public/js/tinymce/tinymce.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    var editor_config = {
      path_absolute : "{{ URL::to('/') }}/",
      selector : "textarea",
      plugins: [
        "advlist autolink lists link image charmap print preview hr anchor pagebreak",
        "searchreplace wordcount visualblocks visualchars code fullscreen",
        "insertdatetime media nonbreaking save table contextmenu directionality",
        "emoticons template paste textcolor colorpicker textpattern"
      ],
      toolbar: "insertfile undo redo | styleselect | bold italic | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | bullist numlist outdent indent | link image media",
      relative_urls: false,
      file_browser_callback : function(field_name, url, type, win) {
        var x = window.innerWidth || document.documentElement.clientWidth || document.getElementByTagName('body')[0].clientWidht;
        var y = window.innerHeight|| document.documentElement.clientHeight|| document.grtElementByTagName('body')[0].clientHeight;
        var cmsURL = editor_config.path_absolute+'laravel-filemanaget?field_name'+field_name;
        if (type = 'image') {
          cmsURL = cmsURL+'&type=Images';
        } else {
          cmsUrl = cmsURL+'&type=Files';
        }

        tinyMCE.activeEditor.windowManager.open({
          file : cmsURL,
          title : 'Filemanager',
          width : x * 0.8,
          height : y * 0.8,
          resizeble : 'yes',
          close_previous : 'no'
        });
      }
    };

    tinymce.init(editor_config);
  </script>
@stop

@section('body')
  <h1>Hello</h1>
  <form method="post" action="addpost">
    {{ csrf_field() }}
    <textarea name="body"></textarea>
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
  </form>

@stop
```

This is the routs

```
Route::get('/', 'HomeController@index');
Route::post('/addpost', 'HomeController@addPost');
Route::get('/{post}', 'HomeController@post');
```

And this is the home controller

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Post;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use App\Http\Requests;

class HomeController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
      return view('index');
    }

    public function post(Post $post)
    {
      return view('post', compact('post'));
    }

    public function addPost(Request $request)
    {
      $post = new Post;
      $post->body = $request->body;
      $post->save();

      return back();
    }
}
```

and I have ony one model Post

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Post extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = ['body'];
}
```

Comment: `'laravel-filemanaget?field_name'+` It's `laravel-filemanager` not `laravel-filemanaget`.

Comment: @peter I made the change also I forgot to add the '=' after the 'laravel-filemanager?field_name', but still the same erorr!

Answer (score 1):

If you did the `laravel-filemanager` installation correctly as suggested [here](http://unisharp.github.io/laravel-filemanager/installation).

Then just putting `'/'` instead of `editor_config.path_absolute` when assigning value to `cmsURL` variable in the code will solve the problem with Laravel 5.4.

Hope it helps.
Didn't check this solution for other versions of Laravel.

This solution is only tested for Laravel 5.4.